# What is the best way to get a path relative to the current address?

Tags: .net, asp.net, relative-path

Suppose I have a resource located in `~/Resources/R1.png`
This resource's relative URL will vary depending on the current address.

For instance:
If I'm at `www.foo.com/A/B/C/D.aspx` and the `www.foo.com/A` is the root path including Virtual Directory, then the path relative to the current address of `~/Resources/R1.png` is `../../../Resources/R1.png`

How can I get this relative path?

**EDIT:**

I want a web path that I can use in a web page, not a server path.

Comment: I was in hurry to leave the office and just give the idea, how can you accomplish this, but you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ResolveUrl("~/Resources/R1.png")

Where '~' is used to represent the root of the application in which the current page/control sits.

Or if the resource is external to the current application but is still found within the virtual directory hierarchy, you can use ResolveUrl("/Resources/R1.png")

Comment: well, it doesnt convert to the ../../xx form. Instead, to converts to a /xx form that browsers can interpret.

Comment: You can always use ResolveClientUrl("~/Resources/R1.png") to get he ../../xxx form if you need that instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
string path = Request.ApplicationPath + "/Resources/R1.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the Virtual Path:

```
Request.Path
```